# Returning promise inside async function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have an AngularJS service method that should return a promise. Within that method is an async call which proceed to do an $http call on success. I am not quite getting the syntax right to return this correctly.

```
// This function should return a promise
function doFacebook() {

  var deferred = $q.defer();

  Facebook.login(function(response) {

    var p = $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/auth/facebook',
      data: {
        token: response.authResponse.accessToken
      }
    });
    p.then(function(data) {
      startSession(data);
      return data;
    }, function(data) {
      return $q.reject(data);
    });
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

I am wanting to return p - not sure how to either attach/replace deferred with it.

Comment: *"I am wanting to return p"* Why, when you could just resolve or reject `deferred` with the data instead? you can't return `p` because it becomes defined long after `doFacebook` has returned.

Comment: Instead of the data you could resolve with the promise itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just resolve deferred object with the promise `p` returned by the http call inside the facebook login callback. it should resolve/reject the passed-in promise automatically.

```
function doFacebook() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  Facebook.login(function(response) {
    var p = $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/auth/facebook',
      data: {
        token: response.authResponse.accessToken
      }
    }).then(function(data) {
      startSession(data);
      return data;
    }, function(data) {
      return $q.reject(data);
    });
    //Here
    deferred.resolve(p);
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

A sample demo:-

```js
///BAD CODE ALERT!!

angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope, $q, $http, $timeout) {

  function doAsync() {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    //Simulating non angular async
    setTimeout(function() {
      //Simulating http call. $timeout also returns a promise, so.
      var p = $timeout(function() {
        //uncomment to test reject scenario
        if ($scope.reject) {
          $scope.reject = false;
          throw Error("OOPS i got rejected");
        }
        return 'Hello, i got resolved!!'
      }).then(function(data) {
        return data;
      }, function(data) {
        return $q.reject(data.message);
      });
      //Here
      deferred.resolve(p);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  }
  $scope.runTest = function() {
    doAsync().then(function(data) {
      $scope.data = data;
    }).catch(function(error) {
      $scope.data = error;
    });
  }
  $scope.rejectTest = function() {
    $scope.reject = true;
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  
  <button ng-click="rejectTest()">Reject and then</button>
  <button ng-click="runTest()">Run Test</button>
  <div>{{data}}</div>
</div>
```